# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55 - while running Gradle build from Jenkins Server

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, java-11

I have looked into various answers related to **Unsupported class file major version 55**, but none are solving mine. 
I have **openjdk11** and **Gradle** wrapper in my local and it builds fine there, but throwing below exception while trying to run through Jenkins server(which has openjdk11).
Please look in to below exception trace and advise.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> failed to read class file /srv/jenkins-slave/workspace/Test/app-test-regression/build/classes/java/test/BVT/checkPageLoads.class

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':test'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:246)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:136)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:201)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:192)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: failed to read class file /srv/jenkins-slave/workspace/Test/app-test-regression/build/classes/java/test/BVT/checkPageLoads.class
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.classVisitor(AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.processTestClass(AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.processTestClass(AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestClassScanner$1.visitClassFile(DefaultTestClassScanner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestClassScanner$ClassFileVisitor.visitFile(DefaultTestClassScanner.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker.walkDir(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:154)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestClassScanner.detectionScan(DefaultTestClassScanner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestClassScanner.run(DefaultTestClassScanner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.TestMainAction.run(TestMainAction.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestExecuter.execute(DefaultTestExecuter.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.DefaultTestExecuter.execute(DefaultTestExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.AbstractTestTask.executeTests(AbstractTestTask.java:469)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:603)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:794)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:761)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.detection.AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.classVisitor(AbstractTestFrameworkDetector.java:123)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: you can go to this path `/srv/jenkins-slave/workspace/Test/app-test-regression/build/classes/java/test/BVT/checkPageLoads.class` and issue a `javap  -v checkPageLoads.class` and look at what it says under `major version:`

Comment: @Eugene - I do not have access to jenkins server so have given it to server team to check. BTW, when I have checked in my local and it says `major version: 54`. I am missing something ??

Comment: you probably are - how are you building/compiling the project?

Comment: I am using Gradle to build my projects. It's working well in my local.

Comment: well look into your gradle configs and the artifacts that you are building - what version do you have there?

Comment: Yes, that was the mistake I did. I was using Gradle wrapper in Jenkins which is 4.8 but was using Gradle 5.1 in my local. Thanks so the help!